# Observer Pattern Closing Observable While Notifying

Tags: c#, multithreading, observer-pattern

I have a observable object that creates a UDP socket. This object has methods to send packets from that UDP socket and a thread to listen for received packets and invoke the PacketReceived event when a packet is received. My question is how should I handle the case when close method of the observer is called while the listener thread is busy invoking PacketReceived event. I can think of 2 solutions.

1. Close method immediately returns and listener thread ends after finished invoking the PacketReceived event. But with this solution listener thread could be still alive after calling the close method. So after the close method returns if I try to close another object that is used in a method that subscribed to PacketReceived event there will be a chance UDP listener thread try to access it after it is closed.
2. Thread that calls the close method waits for the listener thread to finish its work then closes the object. So after the close method returns it is guaranteed no other listener event will be invoked. So after that thread that calls the close method can close other objects that could be used by the UDP listener thread. But the problem is if the thread that calls the close method holds a lock and UDP listener thread tries to hold the same lock while invoking there will be a deadlock.

What is the preferred solution to this problem.

Comment: Show code. No one will read a wall of prose without code. People write they did A and when they show their code it reveals they actually did B. Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

The second option is the better one. For this you can use semaphores. As @Fildor has stated, we have no code to go on, so this will be a "sketch" rather than a direct solution.

It sounds like you can use a simple `SemaphoreSlim` object to control this problem

```
var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
await semaphore.WaitAsync();
try 
{
    // Only one thread at a time can access this. 
}
...
finally 
{
    semaphore.Release();
}
```

Obviously, you are needing cross class safty here, so making a class with a semaphore that is accessable from both places shpuld be enough.

Depanding on your use case and the latency required, you could also use a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim>`, that is a concurrent dictionary of semaphores - here the key would be some kind of unique identifier that the thread that calls the close method and the listner thread both have access to. Then you can do something like

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim> _semaphoreDictionary = 
    new ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim>();
    
... 

var semaphore = _semaphoreDictionary.GetOrAdd(someUniqueKeyForTheThreadPair, new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1));
await semaphore.WaitAsync();
try 
{
    // Only one thread at a time can access this. 
}
...
finally 
{
    semaphore.Release();
    _semaphoreDictionary.Remove(someUniqueKeyForTheThreadPair, out _);
}
```

Without seeing any of your code, that is the best I can offer.